# Ursprung der Redewendung "etwas anwerfen / anschmeißen"

Tags: etymology, idiom

In der Umgangssprache findet die Redewendung "etwas anwerfen / anschmeißen" Gebrauch, um etwas in Gang zu setzen, z.B. um einen...

- Computer hochfahren
- Motor zu starten
- Grill anzuzünden

Es finden sich viele Beispiele in verschiedenen Kontexten. Aber zu keinem mag es passen, dass etwas wortwörtlich "angeworfen" bzw. "angeschmissen" wird.

Worin liegt nun der Ursprung dieser Redenwendung? Ggf. nehme ich sie auch einfach zu wörtlich.

Comment: Interessant: laut Wortschatz Leipzig ist der mit Abstand häufigste Kontext für *anwerfen* übrigens das Wort *Notenpresse*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Laut DWDS](http://zwei.dwds.de/wb/anwerfen) kommt das vom ahd. *anawerfan*, etwas anwerfen, anstoßen, in Gang bringen (z. Bsp. einen Wagen, einen Baumstamm den Hügel hinunter). Wenn man dasselbe Wort für "werfen" und "stoßen" verwendet, kann man das durchaus wörtlich sehen - etwas anstoßen, eben. Daraus ist dann die etwas sinnbildlichere Verwendung in Zusammenhang mit Maschinen geworden. "Anschmeißen" hat sich dann aus "anwerfen" entwickelt, weil in moderner Verwendung werfen und schmeißen Synonyme sind.

Comment: Danke für die verständliche Veranschaulichung der Herleitung. Diese macht aus dem Althochdeutschen durchaus Sinn.

Answer (score 1):

Das kommt aus der Zeit vor dem elektrischen Anlasser, als der Motor eines Fahrzeugs noch mit einer Kurbel in der Mitte der Fahrzeugfront in Gang gesetzt werden musste: das kraftvolle Drücken der Kurbel mit seiner kreisförmigen Bewegung ähnelt einem Wurf.
Siehe [Bild](http://www.kreiszeitung.de/lokales/rotenburg/willy-liess-alle-jung-aussehen-472193.html)